# Need some clarification UTL_FILE package of oracle

Tags: oracle

which encoding format by default does UTL_FILE package uses if we try to extract data from oracle database to csv using UTL_FILE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depends, there are two options.

1. If you using `utl_File.fopen` -> the package expect file in database charset.
2. If you using `utl_file.fopen_nchar` -> the file should be in UTF8 format.

If you one the check db charset use bellow query

`select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';`